# Запрет открытия отладчика или удаление контента при его открытии

Tags: javascript

Есть ли возможность запретить открытие браузерного отладчика средствами JS, знаю есть возможность удалить контент страницы при открытии оного, что-то типа `document.innerHTML = ''`. Встречалось такое, причем как по F12, так и из менюхи браузера.
Как такие вещи можно реализовать?

Comment: никак, это невозможно. Здесь была уже подобная тема. Не стоит забывать, что отладчик может быть открыть _до_ того момента как твоя страница будет загружена, поэтому любой твой клиентский код может быть _отлажен_ :-)

Comment: [Вопрос на английском о facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21692646/2881286)

Comment: Нельзя заблокировать отладчик, кроме того есть текстовые браузеры, от которых это не спасёт. Можно лишь часть кода сделать не изменяемым.

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry, _Можно лишь часть кода сделать не изменяемым._ - каким образом?

Comment: А зачем это вообще может понадобиться?

Comment: @Grundy,  не буду лукавить, делал правки на сайте и человек посчитал, что необязательно платить за работу... поэтому решил повесить баннер с напоминанием, что работа должна оплачиваться... Решил сделать это средствами js, при этом отключить все возможности отследить в каком месте кода он добавляется

Comment: Попробуйте какой-нибудь оbfuscator, например этот: [Javascript Obfuscator
](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) их много разных. И если у вас большой js, то найти ваш баннер будет ну прям очень сложно) По крайней мере, тот, кто будет его вычищать испытает физическую боль в глазах))

Comment: @Mikl   Да, я думал в какую нибудь библиотеку запихать.... хоть в тот же jquery, и обфусцировать ))))